# $index in ng-class for form validation

Tags: angularjs

I want to validate an angular form input and give it a class if is not $valid, the problem is, it´s inside a ng-repeat looping an array of int, and the input name is based on the $index:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in selectedItem.data.ax_ch">
  <div ng-class="{'has-error':!form.ax_$index.$valid}">
     <input type="text" id="ax_{{$index}}" name="ax_{{$index}}" ng-model="item" required=""/>
  </div>
</li>
```

Everything gets the $index in the output, but the ng-class:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in selectedItem.data.ax_ch">
  <div ng-class="{'has-error':!form.ax_$index.$valid}">
     <input type="text" id="ax_0" name="ax_0" ng-model="item" required=""/>
  </div>
</li>
```

What I expected it to be:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in selectedItem.data.ax_ch">
  <div ng-class="{'has-error':!form.ax_0.$valid}">
     <input type="text" id="ax_0" name="ax_0" ng-model="item" required=""/>
  </div>
</li>
```

I have searched and people have similar problems but none of them have been solved so far. Is there any angular-super-hero-master-plus-advanced who can help me with it :) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are constructing the property/key on `form` dynamically, you do the same thing you would in normal Javascript: use `square["bracket"]` notation.

Change your markup to:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in selectedItem.data.ax_ch">
  <div ng-class="{'has-error':!form['ax_' + $index].$valid}">
     <input type="text" id="ax_{{$index}}" name="ax_{{$index}}" ng-model="item" required=""/>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: @MukulSharma Not quite, but when inputs with an `ng-model` directive have a `name` attribute, a property on the form object is added corresponding to the `name` attribute. Similarly, if the `form` element has a `name`, it is published on the scope as that name. Hence why in this code, you can do `$scope.form.ax_1`, for instance.